# MySQL query to find the name and age of the youngest employee in each department

Tags: mysql, database

Given this schema:

```
Emp(eid: integer,ename: string,age: integer,salary: real)
Works(eid:integer,did: integer,pct_time: integer)
Dept(did:integer,budget: real,managerid:integer)
```

I have come up with this:

```
SELECT w.did, MIN(e.age) AS Youngest
FROM Works w INNER JOIN Emp e USING (eid)
GROUP BY w.did
```

Which lists the youngest age for each department. However, I can't figure out how to get the name of each person with that listed age. I can't just add the ename to the SELECT list in this query as that would return the wrong names.

I just tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT e2.ename, e2.age, w2.did
FROM Emp e2 INNER JOIN Works w2 USING (eid),
    (
    SELECT w.did, MIN(e.age) AS Youngest
    FROM Works w INNER JOIN Emp e USING (eid)
    GROUP BY w.did
    ) MyTable
WHERE e2.eid = eid AND e2.age = Youngest
```

It lists multiple people for the same department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT e2.ename, e2.age, w2.did
FROM Emp e2 
JOIN Works w2 USING (eid)
JOIN (SELECT w.did, MIN(e.age) AS Youngest
      FROM Works w 
      INNER JOIN Emp e USING (eid)
      GROUP BY w.did) sq
  ON w2.did = sq.did and e2.age = sq.Youngest
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You need to create a subQuery that has the did and minimum age and then use that to join onto your existing emp table

```
SELECT w.did, ename, e.age AS Youngest
FROM Works w 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT did, MIN(age) minage
            FROM emp e INNER JOIN works w ON e.eid = w.eid
            GROUP BY did) ea
    INNER JOIN Emp e ON w.did = ea.did AND e.age = ea.minage
```

Comment: I came up with something else that returns the same amount of rows as yours. Not sure what is better though. Actually this doesn't work (not counting two typos). It returns multiple people with different ages for the same departments.

Comment: i updated my answer. the last join should be on department not employee

Answer (score 0):

Try this to display youngest emplyee from each native place:

`select p.Nativeplace, p.Name, p.Dobirth from personal p
having p.Dobirth=(select max(Dobirth) from personal p2 where p.Nativeplace=p2.Nativeplace group by p2.Nativeplace);`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT e1.ename, e1.age, FROM Emp as e1, (SELECT eid, MinAge.did, MinAge.minage FROM Works, (SELECT did, MIN(age) as minage FROM Emp, Works where Emp.eid = Works.eid GROUP BY did) as MinAge WHERE Works.did = MinAge.did) as temp WHERE e1.eid = temp.eid AND e1.age = temp.minage;
```